# 64 bit Ubuntu sees half my RAM

Tags: kernel, ram, mythbuntu

This is on my AMD FX(tm)-4100 Quad-Core Processor (according to /proc/cpuinfo) on a machine with two 4GB RAM DIMMs. BIOS shows 8GB RAM installed. Any help would be appreciated.

RAM:
Extreme Performance Sector 5 G Series 8GB DDR3-1333 (PC3-1066) Enhanced Latency Dual Channel Desktop Memory Kit (Two 4GB Memory Modules)

MB: 
GA-78LMT-S2P Socket AM3+ 760G mATX AMD Motherboard

CPU:
FX 4100 Black Edition 3.6GHz Quad-Core Socket AM3+ Boxed Processor

Here's what the software says:

```
$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       3515100    3293656     221444          0      19260    2670352
-/+ buffers/cache:     604044    2911056
Swap:      3650556      90916    3559640

$ uname -a
Linux mythbuntu 3.2.0-30-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 24 16:52:48 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

From lshw:

```
 *-memory
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 20
      slot: System board or motherboard
      size: 4GiB
    *-bank:0
         description: DIMM 1066 MHz (0.9 ns)
         product: None
         vendor: None
         physical id: 0
         serial: None
         slot: A0
         size: 2GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1066MHz (0.9ns)
    *-bank:1
         description: DIMM 1066 MHz (0.9 ns)
         product: None
         vendor: None
         physical id: 1
         serial: None
         slot: A1
         size: 2GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1066MHz (0.9ns)
```

Comment: Are your eally sure you installed 2 x 4 GB RAMS and not 2 x 2 GB? Have you tried to check your ram with a RAM checker which you can start from several Linux boot CDs? Is it cheap RAM or better ones like Corsair? Is your BIOS is up to date? Any bugs reported so far?

Comment: The information reported by lshw comes directly from the motherboard, has nothing to do with what the Linux kernel recognizes. You can verify this with `sudo dmidecode -t 17`. I advise you to review BIOS settings if you're sure the motherboard is recognizing all 8 GB, because from Ubuntu's perspective, it's only reporting 4.

Comment: @roadmr "BIOS shows 8GB RAM installed." from second line of post.

Answer (score 0):

I should update my post to say, "BIOS **showed** 8GB RAM installed." A sneaky fiend swiped the memory from this machine while I was away, and replaced it with two 2GB modules.

Thanks for the fast responses, sorry for taking your time.

Comment: Had this question faved to see how this mystery might be solved. I am still laughing. Made my day! :D

Comment: LOL...
I am checking my ram's now to see if I got a friend like yours...